# How to do lazy loading part of a middle layer business object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lazy-loading, business-objects

I want to build a business object such as an employee class, but I know that 80% of the properties will barely get used. So I wanted to know how I can create the object with the important properties in the constructor and lazy load the ones that are barley used when they are needed (if at all).

I am using asp.net with c#.

Comment: Are you already using an ORM toolset?  many of these support lazy loading.

Comment: no, i am not using ORM. i am hydrating the object properties with a call to a load() method from the constructor. I want to eliminate the useless stuff from being loaded and load those properties only when needed

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious way of doing it is,

```
public Constructor(Object importantPropertyValue)
{
    this.ImportantProperty = importantPropertyValue;
}

public Object ImportantProperty{get; private set;}


private Object _unimportantProperty;

public Object UnimportantProperty
{
    Get
    {
        if(_unimportantProperty == null)
        {
            _unimportantProperty = FetchUnimportantPropertyValue() // how ever you load it
        }

        return _unimportantProperty;
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little? is there code int eh constructor to get the frequently used properties set by default, and  if(_unimportantProperty == null) then set the others as well... i dont get where/how the frequently used properties are set in your sample.

Comment: Check out the modified sample code. The idea is to leave less frequently used properties with null value until their value is requested in which case you check to see if it is loaded and if it's not, then load and return the value.

Comment: can the employee class take a param in the constructor such as userName? and then pull all important data, and leave not important items for later using null?

Comment: I'm not sure about how you are loading the properties but in general that should be possible!

Comment: im loading them in one go with a loadData() call. getting a datareader and assigning values to properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with pure business class, use the [System.Lazy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd642331.aspx).

This class (.net v4 minimum) allow you to defer the filling of a container to the first call, in a thread safe way :

```
public class TestLazy
{
    private Lazy<MyClass> m_lazyObj;


    public MyClass MyClassInstance
    {
        get { return m_lazyObj.Value; }
    }


    public TestLazy()
    {
        m_lazyObj = new Lazy<string>(() => DoTheHeavyJobToGetMyClassInstance);
    }
}
```

If you are using an ORM, as other said in the post, lazy loading will probably be provided by the ORM engine.

*[Edit]: added a code sample*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about lazy loading from a database here then you could build your domain objects using Entity Framework 4.0,  and get lazy loading for free.

Comment: what if i am not using any ORM. just plain old .net and a DB data layer to hydrate the object?

Comment: then you'd have to build it all in manually, using something like the code in @shadowfoxmi's answer.  But there are huge wins to using an ORM, so if you're not using one the first question you should ask yourself is why not?